# Combinatorics and counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

A writing competition has 12 thousand dollars available for prizes.
The jury wants to honor contestants A and B with an equal amount and give C and D some lesser prizes (not necessarily equal). How
many possibilities are there if every prize has to be a multiple of
1000?

I'm having trouble on this question. My initial thought is if A and B's prize is equal, then the amount of the prize must be even. Let's now change the question, let 12 dollars be the prizes and every prize has to be multiple of 1. So, if we let A and B have 10 dollars, the only permutation left for C and D is either 11, 01, or 10. If A and B have 8 dollars, then C and D is either 13,31,40,04,22. But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, any suggestion?

Comment: Can you really have a prize of $0$?

Comment: @saulspatz, yes, that's called honorable mention.

Answer (score 1):

A and B must get over half the pool, so they must each get $4000$ or $5000$.  If they get $4000$, that leaves $4000$ to split between C and D, which can go three ways, $1000-3000, 2000-2000, 3000-1000$.  If they get $5000$, C and D much each get $1000$, so four choices.

Answer (score 0):

Since all prizes are multiples of thousand we can count in thousands and have $a+b+c+d=12, \ \ a=b> c \ge d \ \ a,b,c,d\in N$.

Therefore, we have $12=a+b+c+d=2b+c+d\ge 2(d+2)+d+1+d=4d+5 \implies d\le1.75 \implies d=1 \implies 12=2b+c+1 \implies 11=2b+c \ge 2(c+1)+c=3c+1 \implies c \le 3$ and also c must be odd, since $c=11-2b$. Therefore we have 2 solutions $(4000,4000,3000,1000),(5000,5000,1000,1000)$